# get selected value from multiple <li> using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a unordered list of data, and within each `<li>` i have a hidden input which contain the different values for each `<li>`

```
<form>
    <ul>
    <li><input type="hidden" id="tid" value="1" />Apple</li>
    <li><input type="hidden" id="tid" value="2" />Orange</li>
    <li><input type="hidden" id="tid" value="3" />Pear</li>
    </ul>

</form>
```

how do i retrieve the post value from the hidden input when a particular `<li>` is clicked through jquery??

Comment: Should point out that you are missing the list container element (UL / OL), also you have duplicate ids in your elements ("tid") - change these to "tid1", "tid2", etc...

Comment: sorry its actually unordered list. have added the tag. regarding the tid, i intentionally use the same tid.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(function () {

  $("form li").on('click', function () {
    var tid = $('input[type="hidden"]', this).val();

    alert (tid);
  });

});
```

Comment: worth noting that .on only works since jquery1.7 - use .bind for earlier version

Answer (score 0):

a better practice for your **HTML** implementation is to wrap the content of `li` with a block anchor tag `<a style="display: block" />`. This should make it clickable within the li area.
Then, implement your attribute on the anchor tag.

```
<form id="form_id_here" method="POST" action="semething.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="fruit_id" value="0" />
    <ul id="ul_id_here">
        <li><a fruit_id="1" href="#">Apple</a></li>
        <li><a fruit_id="2" href="#">Orange</a></li>
        <li><a fruit_id="3" href="#">Pear</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Lastly, for your **Javascript** part to handle the clicks:

```
$(function ()
{
    $("#ul_id_here > li > a").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#form_id_here > input[name="fruit_id"]').val($(this).attr("fruit_id"));

        $('#form_id_here').submit(); //or do ajax here
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i found a solution of my own.

here is the html:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="fruit"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="fruitId" id="fruitId">Apple</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="fruit"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="fruitId" id="fruitId">Orange</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$("a#fruit").click(function() {
        var fid = $('input[type="hidden"]', this).val();
        alert (fid);
    });
```